# IOS - Click in Settings.bundle

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I need to do a simple action when user click in multi value list in my preference app (in Settings system)
I show a simple list of my custom sound (like whatsapp or others app did) but instead of putting its on the app tab o same I'd like to put in my preferences.
When user selects a sound (ringtone) I'd like to play the selected sound (like a preview).

Is it possible ? No problem with the list, but I have no idea to handle the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the iOS preferences application, then no, it is not possible.  You cannot modify the operation of this application to run your own code.

If you want to play a sample of the selected sound then you will need to implement this in a preferences section of your own app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to play a short sound.

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourSound" ofType:@"aif"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

Comment: Where I have to put this code ? I have to play sound when user is in the app settings (not inside app).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought that by `my preference app` you meant your own app, and not the Settings app.